# Calculation of partial derivatives of real and imaginary parts of $g(z)=(rez \times imz)^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $g(z)=(rez\times imz)^{1/3}$. Calculate partial derivatives for real and
> imaginary parts, state where they exist and at which points they do
> not exist. Verify Cauchy-Riemann equations at $a=0$.

I'm a bit *confused* about what the problem is asking:

I Let $z=x+iy$ and rewrote $g(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=x^{1/3}y^{1/3}\Rightarrow u=x^{1/3}y^{1/3}$ and $v=0$

$d/dx g(z)=u_x(x,y)=1/3x^{-2/3}y^{1/3}$ and $d/dy g(z)=u_y(x,y)=1/3y^{-2/3}x^{1/3}$

Comment: "Then $u_x=y^{1/3}=v_y=x^{1/3}$ and $u_y=x^{1/3}=-v_x=-y^{1/3}$" Sorry but *what do you mean*?

Comment: I let $g(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then calculated the Cauchy Riemann equations

Comment: What do you find for $u$ and $v$ when you "let $g=u+iv$", exactly?

Comment: $v=0$ and $u=(xy)^{1/3}$

Comment: These are **much** better than your previous $u$ and $v$... Then you can compute $u_x$, $u_y$, $v_x$ and $v_y$ and check where these exist and where these do not, right? Any problem remaining?

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now, thanks :) I should be fine

Comment: I got into trouble of showing Cauchy Riemann at $a=0$, because partial derivatives are not defined at $x=y=0$. Then it means $g(z)$ is not complex differentiable at $0$.